# Get data from start and end date

Tags: java, datetime

I am stuck in a situation where in for loop I am getting date time in this format as String

```
16/07/2014 11:06:33
25/05/2014 06:24:56
21/05/2014 21:37:03
21/05/2014 21:18:54
21/05/2014 21:00:57
21/05/2014 20:41:12
21/05/2014 20:24:50
15/05/2014 09:44:20
13/05/2014 17:08:27
05/05/2014 21:48:27
05/05/2014 12:02:59
```

I am converting it to **SimpleDateFormat** so that by using Start and End date I can get date time in between those date ranges. I also have Start Date and End Date variables. I want to know how can I apply start and end date filter in the current situation?

```
 String testStart = "05/05/2014 12:02:59";
 String testEnd = "15/05/2014 09:44:20";
for(int i=0; i<testOutput.getResultBody().getPaymentResult().size(); i++)
{
 String oldFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
 String newFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
 SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat(oldFormat);
 SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat(newFormat);
 System.out.println("-->" + sdf2.format(sdf1.parse(paymentOutput.getResultBody().getPaymentResult().get(i).getMyDate())));
}
```

I am having difficulty in thinking the logic to use in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
String format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

Date testStart = format.parse("05/05/2014 12:02:59");
Date testEnd = format.parse("15/05/2014 09:44:20");

for(int i=0; i<testOutput.getResultBody().getPaymentResult().size(); i++) {
    String dateStr = paymentOutput.getResultBody().getPaymentResult().get(i).getMyDate();
    Date date = format.parse(dateStr);
    if (date.compareTo(testStart) >= 0 && date.compareTo(testEnd) < 0) {
        System.out.println(dateStr);
    }
}
```

If you are using recent versions of Java, you may also consider using the Joda time API and Streams for better readability.